# Does this group $S=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} S_n$ have a name?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, terminology, symmetric-groups

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$ letters and define

$$S = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} S_n.$$

That is, an element of $S$ is any permutation which permutes finitely many elements of $\mathbb{N}$. We can check it is indeed a group under the usual permutation composition operation.

Does this group have a name, or is it isomorphic to something else more standard? Any attempt to search for it gives me $\mathrm{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ which notably is not isomorphic to $S$ since $S$ is countable (countable union of countable sets) and $\mathrm{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ is not.

Comment: The group you call $S$ is the group of "permutations of finite support, meaning permutations that fix all but finitely many natural numbers."
For more details, see:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620818/colimit-of-symmetric-groups

Comment: [Another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3103005/is-there-a-name-for-the-quotient-of-the-symmetric-group-by-the-finitary-symmetri?rq=1) calls it the _finitary symmetric group_ on $\mathbb N$, which seems like a good name to me (although I'm not sure it's a standard name, and so it would be good to define it anywhere it's used).